# Using Math.Ceiling with ints in C#

Tags: c#, double, decimal

I am trying to take a file and split it into 512kb chunks. To calculate the number of chunks, I need to do some basic math. For some reason, I am having some data loss issues. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I currently have:

```
int chunkSize = 524288;  // 512kb
int fileByteCount = GetFileSizeInBytes();
decimal result = ((decimal)(fileByteCount)) / ((decimal)(chunkSize));
int packetCount = Math.Ceiling(result);   // Doesn't work.
```

I can't use Math.Ceiling because it requires a double. But, I think, I need to use a decimal to do the math. What am I doing wrong? How do I do this basic math operation?

Comment: You can get the *floor* just by using `int` division. You can then add 1 if the file size isn't exactly divisible by the chunk size (using the modulo operator)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: post that as an answer, it's much more sensible than everything else that's been posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use integer math:

```
int chunkSize = 524288;  // 512kb
int fileByteCount = GetFileSizeInBytes();
int packetCount = (fileByteCount + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize;
```

Note that a file size should really be *long*, transferring files larger than 2 gigabytes is not unusual.

Comment: Hurrah for someone getting rid of all the silly casts/conversions.

Answer (score 3):

You could just cast `result` to a double if you want to use `Math.Ceiling`

```
int packetCount = Math.Ceiling((double)result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact error is, but it seems you need to convert the packetCount to an integer when using Math.Ceiling:

```
int chunkSize = 524288;
int fileByteCount = 569344;
decimal result = ((decimal)(fileByteCount)) / ((decimal)(chunkSize));
int packetCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a rounding issue. Try the following.

```
int chunkSize = 524288;  // 512kb 
int fileByteCount = GetFileSizeInBytes(); 
decimal result = (decimal)fileByteCount / (decimal)chunkSize; 
decimal remainder = decimal.Remainder((decimal)fileByteCount, (decimal)chunkSize);
int packetCount = (remainder > 0) ? (int)(result + 1) : (int)result;
```